# write #!/bin/bash -x in the first line, but get no information during execution

Tags: bash

When write `#!/bin/bash -x` in the first line of a bash file (e.g. test.sh), I expect to see some execution information but get nothing... Moreover, when I use the command of `bash -x test.sh` to run the bash file, it will show information.
Any help for what is going on?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you running the script if you don't use `bash -x test.sh`? Do you use `bash test.sh`, or `./test.sh`?

Comment: Yes, and the first answer exactly explains the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shebang only applies when you execute the file directly:

```
myfile
./myfile
/path/to/myfile
```

If you instead execute an interpreter, that interpreter will be used instead, whether or not it's correct and compatible for the script. The best practice is therefore to avoid either of:

```
bash myfile
sh myfile
```

Answer (score 2):

To set debugging to on within your script you will need to use set -x and so:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

.......
```

Comment: It turns out that "#!/bin/bash -x " works as well. I tried that other guy's advice and success. Thanks!